# Why some say that $\int\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ has no elementary solution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Why some say that $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ has no elementary solution? Because I can solve it using only elementary ways:

$$\int\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\int\sin(x)x^{-1}~dx=\sin(x)\ln(x)-\int\cos(x)\ln(x)~dx$$

and then I try to find somewhy but it is elementary.

Comment: All what you did is to write $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx$ in a different form. But you'll still have trouble determining the value of: $\displaystyle\int\cos(x)\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and thus you wouldn't at the end arrive at what you want.

Comment: It is a rather blunt and adventurous thing to claim to be able to do something many others can't and then fail to show it: if you can, then do it (btw, you can't but we'll love to see you trying since that's a nice way to learn)...

Comment: I can't wait to see the second half of your proof.

Comment: @DonAntonio: However, simply trying and failing all the time doesn't necessarily show the problem impossible. It could just mean the solution is simply extremely difficult to find. Actually proving this one is impossible requires a different approach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is one of those integrals that can be shown to have no elementary antiderivative. This is in the realm of differential galois theory and there is a undergrad level proof that $e^{x^2}$ has no elementary solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think people misinterpreted the OP's question. I won't explain what I think the OP means, my answer should make that clear.

---

You're using the term 'elementary' in a different way than what it is meant.

When people say that '$\displaystyle \int\dfrac{{\sin{(x)}}}{{x}}\mathrm dx$ has no elementary solution', what is meant isn't that an antiderivative of $x\mapsto \dfrac{{\sin{(x)}}}{{x}}$ can't be found using only elementary techniques, but rather that an antiderivative of $x\mapsto \dfrac{{\sin{(x)}}}{{x}}$ can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

What you suggest may, a priori, have a chance of being an elementary way of finding an antiderivative (I doubt it), but what you'll find in the end won't be an elementary function.